# Returning a populated VStack from a SwiftUI function

Tags: swiftui

I would like to return different views from a function, a Text or a VStack of a Text and a Button. Here's one of my attempts:

```swift
func buildResponseText2() -> some View {
    if (userData.success) {
        return VStack {
            Text("Well Done")
            Button("Play Again", action: {self.userData.reset()})
        }
    }
    return VStack {
        Text("Unlucky")
    }
}
```

This does not compile, I get the error

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Is there a way to return view containers like VStack with heterogeneous contents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close to the solution, actually. Indeed, you can mark the method as `ViewBuilder` and use `some View` as return type this way:

```
@ViewBuilder
func buildResponseText2() -> some View {
    if userData.success {
        VStack {
            Text("Well Done")
            Button("Play Again", action: {self.userData.reset()})
        }
    } else {
        Text("Unlucky")
    }
}
```

If you prefer, you can also use a computed property the same way:

```
@ViewBuilder
var responseText2: some View {
    if userData.success {
        VStack {
            Text("Well Done")
            Button("Play Again", action: {self.userData.reset()})
        }
    } else {
        Text("Unlucky")
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like this is arguably a better solution than the accepted answer, although they're both similar. Avoids having to wrap each branch of the if-else content in an `AnyView` – less visual noise & code to change in future

Answer (score 12):

Use type erasing `AnyView` as return type, as below

```
func buildResponseText2() -> AnyView {
    if (userData.success) {
        return AnyView(VStack {
            Text("Well Done")
            Button("Play Again", action: {self.userData.reset()})
        })
    }
    return AnyView(VStack {
        Text("Unlucky")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Extract layout and Preserve the original type:

You should implement a custom view with a custom view builder so you can return different types. Also, you may want to remove the `VStack` from the return value, so you can decide to use a different layout later without any need to change the content.

So implement this:

```
struct StackContent: View {
    let success: Bool

    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        switch success {
        case true:
            Text("Well Done")
            Button("Play Again") { print("clicked") }
        case false:
            Text("Unlucky")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have this:

```
func buildResponseText2() -> some View {
    VStak { // <- you can change it to other layout containers
         StackContent(success: userData.success)
    }
}
```

<sub>Maybe you don't need the function at all anymore ;)</sub>

Note that there is no need to write `@ViewBuilder` from Swift 5.3 (Xcode 12)